# How to loop through session array in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to loop through the session. But I can't seem to get the expected results.
I'm still trying to explore things. So please teach me a better way to do this. If you find my code unsecure or inappropriate. 
First I have this login form:

```
<form name="x" action="login.php" method="post">

Username:<input type="text" name="uname" value=""></input><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="pword" value=""></input>
<input type="submit" value="login"></input>
</form>
```

And here's login.php which sets the session if the record is found on the mysql database:

```
<?php
require_once("conn.php");

$username=$_POST['uname'];
$pword=md5($_POST['pword']);

echo $username."<br/>";
echo $pword;

$check=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Uname='$username' AND Hpword='$pword'");

if(mysql_num_rows($check)==0){
    header('Location:loginform.php');
}else{

    session_start();

    while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
        $_SESSION['uid'].=$result['ID'];
        $_SESSION['uname'].=$result['Uname'];


    }

}
?>
```

And here's the file which loops through the session:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo "Logged in users:<br/>";


foreach($_SESSION as $sir){


}

echo "User id: ". $_SESSION['uid']."<br/>";
echo "Username: ".$_SESSION['uname']."<br/>";

?>
```

I get this:

[image]

While I'm expecting to get something like this:

User id: 1
Username: yoh

User id: 2
Username: max

Comment: Try to avoid SQL injection or problems: use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting POST data into a query

Comment: @Frosty only **string** data from **any** source it should be.

Comment: Obviously, however thanks for pointing this out for any beginner reading this.

Answer (score 6):

$_SESSION is available only for the visitor who opens the page actually. (It would be nice to see everyone's $_SESSION variables, isn't it?)

You may want to store these $_SESSION vars in your db then loop through them.

Update:

- create a sessions table where you can store your currently logged in users
- every time when a logged in user opens a page, increment a value (timestamp) like `last_seen`
- at the same time check dead sessions (e.g. delete all rows where `last_seen` value is smaller than `now` - server's session lifetime

Comment: like make a table for current users? or make switches on user table?(1 if logged in, 0 if not). Is that what you want me to do?

Comment: just updated my answer with an outline on how to do this easily.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from extremely correct fabrik's answer, just a few lines on your code:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $sir){

}
```

this loop obviously does nothing. you can't get any output from the code that outputs nothing :)

Also, if you want to store multiple values into session, like in shopping cart, you have to store in in array, not long concatenated string:

```
    $_SESSION['cart'][] =$result;
```

will produce an array called $_SESSION['cart'] which can be iterated the way you desired:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){
  echo "Item id: ".$result['id'].", name: ".$result['name']."<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
{
    echo $name."=".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: The question suggests the output of every users session should be done. The correct anwer is that it cannot be done iterating over $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** : non numerical index.

In login.php

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
     $_SESSION[$result['Uname'].$result['ID']] = array(
         "uid"=>$result['ID'], 
         "uname"=>$result['Uname']
     );
}
```

And in you foreach

```
foreach($_SESSION as $uinfos){
    echo "User id: ".$uinfos["uid"]."<br/>Username: ".$uinfos["uname"]."<br/>";
}
```

Like this you have only one entry for each user.

Comment: $_SESSION array doesn't support numeric indices

Comment: it's still won't work, as PHP variable name cannot be started from number.

Comment: also, it's just a bad practice to iterate over $_SESSION itself. there can be (and most likely would be) other items, like shopping cart, user preferences etc

Answer (score -1):

why don't you store it like

$_SESSION[$uid] = $name;  or $_SESSION[] = array('uid' => $uid, 'name' => $name);

then you can simply iterate through all entries..

```
foreach($_SESSION as $uid=> $name){
   ....
}
```

or

```
foreach($_SESSION as $userArray){
    $uid = $userArray['uid']; 
    $name = $userArray['name']; 
}
```

Comment: I think that if someone connects from another client (browser, machine...), this won't work...

Comment: $_SESSION array doesn't support numeric indices