# Unsetting multi-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to unset a certain value in a session array in php. I would like to ask if there's a better way in doing this:

```
    <?php

    session_start();


    if(isset($_GET['Uname'])){
        echo "Uname is set!";


            $uname=$_GET['Uname'];


        echo count($_SESSION['user']);

        for($x=0; $x < count($_SESSION['user']); $x++ ){

            if($_SESSION['user'][$x]['Uname']==$uname){

                unset($_SESSION['user'][$x]['Uname']);
            }

        }


    }else{


    }

?>
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing using a foreach loop?Or another method

Comment: Looks like you doesn't understood $_SESSION's fundamentals yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403721/how-to-loop-through-session-array-in-php One. Session. Per. User. Also you may want to meet session_destroy: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure unsetting `user` should solve that. You don't need a loop. Try this, refreshing page will surely set value at one time and other unset it's value.

```
<?php

session_start();

$array = array('arr', 'arr', 'arr', 'arr', 'arr', 'arr');

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    print_r($_SESSION['user']);
    unset($_SESSION['user']);   
}
else{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $array;
    echo "user session was set";
}
```

And according to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php , using `count()` in loop is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to unset a certain value in a session array in php. I would like to ask if there's a better way in doing this.

I can assure you that the best way to unset a variable is to use `unset()` function on it.